# Get name-value pair from object?

Tags: jquery, object, dom, syntax

I have an object

```
  var foodLoads = {
    orange: 6.7,
    apple: 5.6,
    banana: 12.7,
    grapes: 16.3,
    peach: 2.7,
    pear: 6.5,
    mango: 16.1,
    blueberries: 9.3,
    grapefruit: 1.7,
    strawberries: 3.5,
    tangerine: 3.1,
    watermelon: 8,
    duck: 0,
    beef: 0,
    chicken: 0,
    ham: 0,
    turkey: 0,
    elk: 0,
    pork: 0,
    fish: 0,
    eggs: 0,
    lamb: 0,
    applejuice: 11.8,
    cranberryjuice: 23.3,
    orangejuice: 14.4,
    carrotjuice: 8.6,
    lemonade: 24.3,
    hotchocolatemix: 10.2,
    tomatojuice: 3.5,
    chocolatemilk: 13.3,
    almondmilk: 0.02,
    soymilk: 4,
    wholewheatbread: 6.1,
    whitebread: 10.7,
    bagel: 30,
    waffle: 13.8,
    pancake: 5.3,
    croissant: 12.2,
    muffin: 28.8,
    englishmuffin: 21.3,
    doughnut: 15.2,
    oatmeal: 12.6,
    quinoa: 20.4,
    wholegrainbread: 7.1 
  }

$('.submit-items').on('click', function() {
    var type = $('.food-list .active li');
    var foodName = $(type).text();
    var value = foodLoads[foodName];
    $(type).parent().append('<p>' + value + '</p>');  

})
```

In the above on-click function, what I'm essentially trying to do is:

1. Get the property (from the foodLoads object) whose name matches the text found in the "foodName" variable
2. Put that property's VALUE in a paragraph
3. Append that paragraph into the "type" variable's parent.

Here is the corresponding HTML:

```
<ul class="food-list">
   <div class="active orange">
      <li> orange</li>
      <select class="serving-size"><option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</ul>

<ul class="food-list">
   <div class="active eggs">
      <li> orange</li>
      <select class="serving-size"><option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</ul>

<ul class="food-list">
   <div class="active bagel">
      <li> orange</li>
      <select class="serving-size"><option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
         <option value="3">3</option>
         <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</ul>
```

*The divs in the `<ul>` are created dynamically as the user checks a checkbox.

```
 $('input').on('ifChecked', function(event) {       
    var liText = $(this).parent().parent().text();
    var wrappedUp = $('<div class="active"><li>' + liText + '</li><select class="serving-size"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option></select></div>');
    $('.food-list').append(wrappedUp);
    $(wrappedUp).addClass('' + liText + '');
```

*From the testing I have done, I see that everything works fine except the "value" variable.

This makes me ask the question:

Is that ("value" variable) the correct syntax for retrieving the value of a property that's in an object (foodLoads)?

Help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: the way you ask for the value is correct. Check which foodName you ask for. My guess, your selector (the type) might not be correct. By the way, since type is an jQuery object, you don't need to wrap it into another selector method, you can use type.text() directly.

Comment: If your `value` variable isn't working right, then it's probably because your `foodName` variable isn't right which is probably because the jQuery before it isn't right.  We need to see the HTML that goes with this Javascript code to know where the problem is.

Comment: maybe it would help to see the corresponding html, but i think axel.mitchel and jfriend00 got the point here.

Comment: It seems likely that your jQuery should be `var type = $('.food-list li.active');`, but we'd need to see your HTML to know for sure.

Comment: Also, `$(type).parent()` is going to be a `<ul>` tag so appending a `<p>` to that is not legal HTML.  We're just guessing a lot here without seeing your HTML.

Comment: Here's some HTML that works with a slightly fixed version of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/2efhcgxp/.  This shows that the concept of looking up the text in your table works if you have the right code for the right HTML.

Comment: @axel.michel - I actually double checked the selector, and it works properly, it selects exactly what I want it to. Also, thanks for the tip, I am now using type.text(). Does this mean I should also use type.parent().append() instead of $(type).parent().append()?

Comment: @jfriend00 - The li's are actually wrapped in divs with a class of .active, so parent() should put the <p> inside the div which itself is contained in an <ul>

Comment: Uh, you can't wrap an `<li>` in a `<div>`.  That's not legal HTML.  An `<li>` parent should be a `<ul>` or `<ol>` or `<menu>`.  From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li): ***The HTML <li> element (or HTML List Item Element) is used to represent an item in a list. It must be contained in a parent element: an ordered list (<ol>), an unordered list (<ul>), or a menu (<menu>)***.  Why are you not showing us the ACTUAL HTML to we can stop guessing what it looks like!

Comment: Your HTML is illegal.  See my previous comment about parents for an `<li>`.  And, your `.text()` for the `<li>` has a space in it which will probably make your `foodname` have a space in it and then not work in your lookup.

Comment: @jfriend00 - The direct parent is a <div> and the parent of that is an <ul>. That still not legal HTML?

Comment: No.  Not legal HTML.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I just added the HTML, I'm not the Flash geez.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Alright, thanks for the tip, I'll go ahead and change the HTML, but, legality aside, could that html still work in producing the required result or would it get in the way of the function?

Comment: Use trim to remove the leading space `var foodName = $.trim($(type).text());`

Comment: My exasperation about you not adding the HTML is that we solved your issue minutes after seeing the HTML, but it took a dozen comments and almost an hour to get you to do so. I see you're relatively new here.  When you post a question, you should be checking back a few times in the first 15 minutes or so after posting so you can clarify things that are confusing people or missing from the question. Doing so will get your answers faster and more efficiently by the community.  And, many questions without proper explanation are outright closed in the first 30 minutes if the OP is not responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you've included your HTML, there are several problems here.

The direct parent of an `<li>` must be an `<ol>`, `<ul>` or `<menu>` tag.  So your HTML is not legal.  See [reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li):

> The HTML `<li>` element (or HTML List Item Element) is used to represent
>   an item in a list. It must be contained in a parent element: an
>   ordered list (`<ol>`), an unordered list (`<ul>`), or a menu (`<menu>`)

Then, once you fix that and the corresponding selectors in your jQuery, your table lookup is probably not working because **you have a leading space in your HTML**.

```
<li> orange</li>
```

That will put a leading space on your `foodName` variable which will cause it to not find anything in the object lookup.

Once you fix the HTML and corrsponding jQuery selectors to make legal HTML, you can either remove the leading space inside the `<li>` tag or you can trim off any leading trailing whitespace with:

```
var foodName = $(type).text().trim();
```

You will also have to make sure that you don't have more than one `<li>` that matches `.active` because if you do, then `.text()` will grab the text from both of them and concatenate it and that will not match any key in your object either.

Comment: I just added the js code used to create the dynamic divs: 

is there any reason there should be any leading whitespace in the <li> with what I've got there?

Comment: @Edson - That depends entirely whether `$(this).parent().parent().text()` which is the source of the text in the `<li>` has a space in it or not.  You don't show us that so we don't really know. You are probably just safer to use `.trim()` before doing the lookup just in case.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I'll go ahead and make the edits and make an update on what happens. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It worked with .trim()! Although, I'll be making the changes to have legal html since I don't wan't any bad html.

Comment: In regards to not having more than one <li> that matches .active, that is exactly what I have. When I only have one div created (by user selecting checkboxing)then the function works. 
However, any more, and it doesn't. 
Is there a way around this, such as .each()?

Comment: @Edson - What do you want the behavior to be when you have more than one active?  If you want to process each match individually, then you would have to process use `.each()` on your list of matching `<li>` tags and process each one separately inside the `.each()` loop.